# AWS Lambda - different dead letter queue based on Lambda alias

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've two SQS queues one for *test* stage and one for *prod* stage and a single Lambda function with *test* and *prod* aliases, each alias is triggered by a SQS event of the corresponding queue.

I was wondering if there's a way to specifcy a DLQ for each alias (I'm using a SAM template to define the Lambda function) of the Lambda or I would like to understand which is the best practice to handle such requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward to add your DLQs - and the test-prod alias setup you have does not complicate things at all.

Add a `RedrivePolicy` to your two Queue definitions.  Here's the prod half the code:

```yaml
  # template.yaml

  # new: define a new queue to be the prod DLQ
  MyProdDLQ:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: this-queue-captures-errors-sent-from-the-prod-queue

  MyProdQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: this-queue-feeds-the-prod-alias-lambda
      VisibilityTimeout: 60  
    # new: assign the DLQ
    RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt MyProdDLQ.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 5
```

Note:  You might be tempted to define the DLQ on the lambda function itself.  Confusingly, the DLQ on the lambda function is for [asynchronous (event-driven) invocations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html), not SQS sources.  The [docs warn about this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig), but it is easy to miss.